# installing Windows Vista after installed Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric

Tags: installation, windows

I installed Windows Vista and Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.
Now I need to reinstall windows vista.

Is it possible to install windows without ubuntu reinstalling?

Comment: Just edited your posat to be more clear that there is no Ubuntu 11.11, it's 11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, however, usually windows overrides the boot record, which makes linux seem unbootable. After installing windows you can boot from the ubuntu live cd and repair the boot sector, if necessary.

Comment: Doesn't Windows also have problems when there are more than 4 primary partitions?

Comment: Windows does have issues with Drives with more than 4 Primary partitions, but you can still have more using extended partitions.

Comment: Not only windows as far as i know. However, as I understood him, he wanted to reinstall his windows without changing the partitions...

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. When you reinstall Windows Vista. Windows boot loader will take over the MBR which will make 11.10 seem unbootable. However after installing Vista You can simply download EasyBCD for Windows and simply add GRUB (legacy) to MBR which will enable you to boot into 11.10 as Grub will overwrite the Windows boot loader in the MBR

Answer (score 0):

Thx to all! I've done it.
I found a good description here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair